# insert twig in html jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I'm trying to insert html with twig via jQuery but the twig is escaped as text. Is there a way to escape the twig when it is appended with jquery ?

```
var html = `
         {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') and app.user %}

        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropup">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ path('easyadmin')}}"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i> Administrar sistema</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <i id ="hide-footer" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove white gi-2x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}`


$('#reshow-footer').append(html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') and app.user %}
    <script>
        var html = 'your text or url="{{ path('rout_name') }}"';
        $('#reshow-footer').append(html);
    </script
{% endif %}
```

Comment: nice idea, what about the {{ path('easyadmin')}} and other twig vars?

Comment: When you are in twig file, you can write every twig code wherever you want(of course between curly brackets or other signs)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Twig is interpreted by server (like PHP).
So you can't write twig in jQuery (because the page is already loaded).

So the solution is to encapsulate your jQuery code into your twig condition.